# Heroku, Procfile and gitignore

Tags: git, scala, heroku

I have this scala http-akka project called yutani hosted on Heroku.
This project works by doing a heroku local command.
The path of the procfile is "web: target/universal/stage/bin/yutani".

However, when I see the logs of my app, I can see the following error :  bash: target/universal/stage/bin/yutani: No such file or directory

I understand that I must use the sbt JavaServerAppPackaging and do the stage phase before comitting to Heroku. When I do this thase, the target/universal/bin/yutani file is properly created.

But I always thought it was good practice to put the target directory into the .gitignore file in order to prevent it's commit.

However, if I don't commit the target directory, then is it normal than the remote server can't found the yutani file ??? Or is the project supposed to be 
rebuilt on Heroku once git pushed ?

I feel like I'm missing something here... Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out as I suspected I could very well let my target in my .ignore file as I learned that my project is indeed rebuilt on the Heroku server.

I tried to clone the git from another computer and I saw a part of source code was missing. Back to my other computer where I started the project, I checked and for some reason the syntaxic coloration of IntelliJ did not show the folder as uncommited. So basically, when I remote pushed, the app couldn't compile and I couldn't see it in the logs - because I think build logs and run logs are not the same in Heroku ?

I decided to go manual on git and readded the file and pushed them using command line instead of using git IDEA integration. Turns out this method is much, much better because when you do the git push you can see all the details of your build!

My issue is therefore resolved !

Comment: Yes, build logs are usually displayed when you `git push heroku master`, you do it differently?

Comment: Aa, it would explain your problem then ^_^ You really need to know heroku's output on the `git push`